# SQL islands - find consecutive address ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have data that represents address ranges along streets.  I need to group the ranges when they are consecutive.  I've tried some of the other solutions for SQL gaps & islands, but can't seem to make anything work.

```
FullName  | City       | FromRight | ToRight | FromLeft | ToLeft 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
W Main St | Townsville | 100       | 198     | 101       | 199
W Main St | Townsville | 200       | 298     | 201       | 299
W Main St | Townsville | 500       | 598     | 501       | 599
W Main St | Cityburg   | 600       | 698     | 601       | 699
E 1st Ave | Townsville | 100       | 398     | 301       | 399
E 1st Ave | Townsville | 400       | 416     | 401       | 417
E 1st Ave | Townsville | 418       | 458     | 419       | 459
```

I need to be able to find consecutive values based on the low address (the From Right) and the high address (the To Left) when the street name and City are the same.  So my result table would look like:

```
FullName  | City       | FromRight | ToLeft 
--------------------------------------------
W Main St | Townsville | 100       | 299     
W Main St | Townsville | 500       | 599
W Main St | Cityburg   | 600       | 699
E 1st Ave | Townsville | 100       | 459
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are  you sure, looks like `E 1st Ave | Townsville | 100       | 398     | 301       | 399` is missing 101..299.

Comment: your result set assumes that right will always be less than left but consider when the right range is fully within the left range e.g. NW 2nd st FromRight 150 ToRight 180 FromLeft 101 ToLeft 199 then the next row is FromRight 200 ToRight 298 FromLeft 201 ToLeft 199.  So in that case what would the aggregate FromRight be?  It cannot be 150 because that would cut off 101-149 for the Left Side of the street.  Would it then be FromLeft - 1 as FromRight?

Comment: I guess with the nuances I would have to wonder why combine/simplify the records? Would it be better to maintain the extra records and just aggregate after your match? or assign a block number to a segment and aggregate that way?

Comment: @Serg - Yes, that segment would be a long street that allows for addresses anywhere between 100 and 399.  It isn't broken into smaller pieces.

Comment: @Matt - Our streets locally always have the even addresses on the right side.  So, we always have the right side lower than the left.  That's a good point, though, it could be different for different areas.

Comment: When geocoding/matching in these manners it would be better to leave them as smaller segments (In my opinion).  and I get the point of Right Side versus Left Side even/odd I think that is fairly standard but.  because houses are not always on the right when on the left or vice versa it can lead to situations where right address range is fully contained within the left address range and NOT less than the left side.......

Comment: @Matt - That makes sense.  Our road segments happen to be the full potential range along a road, and aren't representative of the locations of houses.  So, we always use the lowest possible address and the highest possible address.  I'm trying to get a table of the consecutive values because I want to compare my data (GIS data) to address tables used in 911.  So, I'm trying to format my data in the same way they have their data formatted - and they use longer segments than I do.  That way I can make sure that we aren't missing a road range that they have in their system.

Comment: got it yeah not a fun task, I think ArcGIS does have a tool for the purpose if you are on ERSI platform, but I don't remember.  I guess I am trying to think of the reverse of E 1st Ave | Townsville | 100 | 398 | 301 | 399  so it would be E 1st Ave | Townsville | 300 | 398 | 101 | 399.....  but I am not aware of your data so good luck!

Comment: @Matt - Yeah, it definitely isn't fun.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution relies on having a tally table. But it's pretty straightforward once that's in place. (Hat tip to John above for providing the sample data in an easy to consume format in another answer).

```
Declare @YourTable Table (FullName varchar(100),City varchar(100),FromRight int,ToRight int,FromLeft int, ToLeft int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 198     , 101       , 199),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 200       , 298     , 201       , 299),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 500       , 598     , 501       , 599),
('W Main St' , 'Cityburg'   , 600       , 698     , 601       , 699),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 398     , 301       , 399),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 400       , 416     , 401       , 417),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 418       , 458     , 419       , 459);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [yt].[FullName], [yt].[City], [n].[n],
    [n].[n] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [yt].[FullName], [yt].[City] ORDER BY [n]) AS [rn]
    FROM [Util].[dbo].[Numbers] AS [n]
    JOIN @YourTable AS [yt]
        ON [n].[n] BETWEEN [yt].[FromRight] AND [yt].[ToLeft]
)
SELECT [FullName], [City], MIN([n]), MAX([n])
FROM [cte]
GROUP BY [FullName] ,
         [City], [rn]
ORDER BY [FullName], [City], MIN([n]);
```

The key observation here is that if you're inside of a contiguous range, both `row_number()` and the tally table increase at the same rate (i.e. one per row), so their difference will be identical for rows within the group.

Comment: Very good use of tally table. I did not think about using this. Although, I use it heavily for string split functions prior to SQL server 2016 which nicely comes with its own

Comment: This seems promising, but when I try it against my full dataset, I'm getting some roads with great results and some that have a lot of duplicates.  I'll have to play around with it more and figure out what is going on.  Thanks, though.

Comment: I'm curious to see what is different in your source data that would cause dupes. Aggregation *should* take care of any of that.

Comment: Much better.  I use my tally table all the time.  It never even dawned on me for the example.

Comment: Seriously, what a fabulous technique!  I've twisted myself into knots generating Group Keys.   So clean and elegant. (as I hang my head in shame)

Comment: @sernst: It just occurred to me: are you sure that your roads are exactly the same? I.e. no trailing spaces or anything weird like that? Run the values through `binary_checksum()` to make sure.

Comment: @BenThul - It was a problem with my data.  This works great!  Thank you very, much.

Comment: @sernst: Out of curiosity, what was the issue? I know you already paid me in Internet Points, but paying me in knowledge is more beneficial. :)

Comment: @BenThul: We have some streets that we split into divided roadways (picture a highway where the north-bound lanes are completely separate from the south-bound lanes - and you couldn't possibly move your car into the oncoming traffic).  On those types of roadways, we only address one side - so we have 0s for the FromRight, ToRight or FromLeft, ToLeft.  Once I accounted for those zeros, things looked a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable Table (FullName varchar(100),City varchar(100),FromRight int,ToRight int,FromLeft int, ToLeft int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 198     , 101       , 199),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 200       , 298     , 201       , 299),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 500       , 598     , 501       , 599),
('W Main St' , 'Cityburg'   , 600       , 698     , 601       , 699),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 398     , 301       , 399),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 400       , 416     , 401       , 417),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 418       , 458     , 419       , 459)
```

---

```
;with cteBase  as (Select FullName,City,R1=FromRight,R2=ToLeft From @YourTable
    ),ctePass1 as (
                   Select A.FullName,A.City,R1=B.Pass1R1,R2=B.Pass1R2
                     From cteBase A
                    Cross Apply (Select Pass1R1=min(R1),Pass1R2=max(R2) 
                                  From  cteBase 
                                  Where FullName=A.FullName and City=A.City and (A.R1 Between R1-1 and R2+1 or A.R2 Between R1-1 and R2+1)) B
    ),ctePass2 as (
                    Select A.FullName,A.City,R1=B.Pass1R1,R2=B.Pass1R2
                     From  ctePass1 A
                     Cross Apply (Select Pass1R1=min(R1),Pass1R2=max(R2) 
                                   From  ctePass1 
                                   Where FullName=A.FullName and City=A.City and (A.R1 Between R1-1 and R2+1 or A.R2 Between R1-1 and R2+1)) B
)
Select Distinct 
       FullName
      ,City
      ,FromRight = R1
      ,ToLeft    = R2
 From  ctePass2
 Order By 1 Desc,2 Desc, 3
```

Returns

```
FullName    City        FromRight   ToLeft
W Main St   Townsville  100         299
W Main St   Townsville  500         599
W Main St   Cityburg    600         699
E 1st Ave   Townsville  100         459
```

Comment: Nice approach. I tested it with my test data below that throws in some new rows and gaps in data and it worked as mine did. I'm still trying to figure yours out but i'm sure mine is even more confusing haha.

Comment: @scsimon Very kind and comforting to know you got the same results.  Personally I dig seeing other approaches.  There's always something to be gained.  That said, Shnugo's brilliant XML makes my brain bleed.

Comment: Thank you.  This isn't quite working on my full dataset, but it gives me a few ideas to try out.  In the full dataset, I'm getting too many records back.

Comment: @sernst No worries, I'm chewing on Ben's answer.  Much smarter

Comment: @sernst If you don't have a numbers/tally table like in Ben's answer, you could clone ctePass2 as ctePass3 ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are on modern version and assuming that 1) only `FromRight` and `ToLeft`  matter according to your comment, 2) intervals never overlap

```
Declare @YourTable Table (FullName varchar(100),City varchar(100),FromRight int,ToRight int,FromLeft int,ToLeft int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 198     , 101       , 199),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 200       , 298     , 201       , 299),
('W Main St' , 'Townsville' , 500       , 598     , 501       , 599),
('W Main St' , 'Cityburg'   , 600       , 698     , 601       , 699),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 100       , 398     , 301       , 399),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 400       , 416     , 401       , 417),
('E 1st Ave' , 'Townsville' , 418       , 458     , 419       , 459);

select FullName, City
   , FromRight = max(case startFlag when 1 then FromRight end)
   , ToLeft = max(case endFlag when 1 then ToLeft end)
from (
    select *
       , grp = sum(startFlag) over(partition by FullName, City order by FromRight)
    from (
        select *
          , startFlag = Case FromRight when lag(ToLeft,1,-1) over (partition by FullName , City order by FromRight) + 1 then 0 else 1 end
          , endFlag = Case ToLeft when lead(FromRight,1,-1) over (partition by FullName , City order by ToLeft) - 1 then 0 else 1 end
        from @YourTable
        ) flags
    ) groups
group by FullName, City, grp
order by FullName, City, FromRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED TO HANDLE GAPS IN ROWS**

This isn't the best approach i'm sure but it works with your test data. It was fun to play around with anyways. I don't understand the real use in it, and just because you **can** doesn't mean you **should** all the time, but again it was a fun challenge :)

```
;with cte1 as(
select
    FullName,
    City,
    FromRight,
    ToRight,
    FromLeft,
    ToLeft,
    case 
        when lag(ToLeft) over(PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) is null  or lag(ToLeft) over(PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) + 1 <> FromRight then FromRight
    end as NewFromRight,
    case
        when lead(FromRight) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) - 1 = ToLeft then NULL
        when lead(FromRight) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) is null then ToLeft
        when lead(FromRight) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) - 1 <> ToLeft then ToLeft
        else ToLeft
    end as NewToLeft
from #cities),

------this CTE is needed because I couldn't figure out how to do it without it
------It takes the max of the previous CTE for the given partition. 
------Nested windows functions aren't allowed hence the second cte
cte2 as(
select distinct
    FullName,
    City,
    NewFromRight as FromRight,
    NewToLeft as ToLeft
from
    cte1
where
    NewFromRight is not null and NewToLeft is not null
union all
select distinct
    FullName,
    City,
    --max(NewFromRight) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) as FromRight,
    --max(NewToLeft) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight) as ToLeft
    case 
        when NewFromRight is null then lag(NewFromRight) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight)
        else NewFromRight
    end as FromRight,
    case 
        when NewToLeft is null then lead(NewToLeft) over (PARTITION BY FullName, City ORDER BY FullName, City, FromRight)
        else NewToLeft
    end as ToLeft
from cte1
where
    NewFromRight is null or NewToLeft is null)

select * from cte2
where FromRight is not null and ToLeft is not null 
order by FullName, FromRight
```

If anyone wants to play with this... here is some test data. Just replace `YourTable` in the first CTE with `#cities`

```
select
'W Main St' as FullName,'Townsville' as City,100 as FromRight,198 as ToRight,101 as FromLeft,199 as ToLeft
into #cities
UNION ALL SELECT 'W Main St','Townsville',200,298,201,299
UNION ALL SELECT 'W Main St','Townsville',500,598,501,599
UNION ALL SELECT 'W Main St','Cityburg',600,698,601,699
UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',100,398,301,399
UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',400,416,401,417
UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',418,458,419,459

UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',470,458,419,479
UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',490,458,419,499
UNION ALL SELECT 'E 1st Ave','Townsville',500,458,419,501
```

Comment: I can think of a few address use case this will probably break down on such as when rights are fully contained within lefts, lefts end before 1+ will be continuous.  Granted those use cases are not in the OP.  As I break down your query i looks/reads like it shouldn't work but it does due to the partitioned RUNNING MAX(), RUNNING MIN() would have the same affect but MIN() for FromRight makes more since when reading code..  Anyway, good thought process!  I will note that because you partition by Fullname and city you shouldn't need those in the order by but they don't hurt their either

Comment: haha thanks @matt i'm not sure if it was the right thought process but it's where my noggin led me. Like i said, i'm sure there is a better cleaner way, and probably more correct

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, I'm on 2008 R2 and lead/lag aren't available.  I might try and get a test db on 2012 so I can try this approach.

Comment: No worries. The others are faster than mine anyhow

Comment: I'm sure you will agree Ben's answer is simply elegant.  What a great technique to generate Group Keys.   Again, its always a good day when I learn something new.